# Radon-Nikodym Equivalent Measures

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, radon-nikodym

**Problem statement:** For a measure space $ (\Omega, \mathcal{F}, \mathrm{μ})$ : ${μ} $ is positve and finite, show the following:
The set function

$\nu(A) = \int_Af d\mu$  , $A \in \mathcal{F}$

defines a new positive measure on $\mathcal{F}$ equivalent to $\mathrm{μ}$, iff ${f}$ is strictly positive $\mathrm{μ}$-a.e and $\mathrm{μ}$-integrable.

**My question:** The forward direction obviously holds true from the Radon-Nikodym theorem. I'm having trouble proving the last tip of the reverse direction. Starting with a funcion ${f}$ as described above, It's not too hard to show that ${ν}$ is indeed a measure. It's also trivial that $\nu \ll \mu$. But how can we **rigorously** prove that $\mu \ll \nu$ ? I'm sure we've all used the argument that when for a strictly positive ${f}$, it holds:

$\int_Af d\mu = 0$ , then $\Rightarrow$ $\mu(A) = 0 $,

but what would be a formal and stringent proof of this property/claim ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $f$ be strictly positive, $A_1 := f^{-1} [1, \infty)$ and $A_n := f^{-1}\left[\frac{1}{n}, \frac{1}{n - 1}\right)$ for $n \geq 2$.

Then we have
$$
\mu(A) = \int_{A}{\mu(dx)}
= \int_{A}\mu(dx) \frac{f(x)}{f(x)} 
= \int_{A}\mu(dx) \frac{f(x)}{f(x)} \sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}{1_{A_n}}(x) \\
= \sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} \int_{A}{\mu(dx) \frac{f(x)}{f(x)} 1_{A_n}}(x) 
\leq \sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} \int_{A}{\mu(dx) f(x) \frac{1}{\frac{1}{n} }} 
= \sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}{(n \cdot 0)} = 0.
$$

An alternative proof by contradiction would be the following. Suppose that $\mu(A) > 0$. Then
$$
\int_{A}{\mu(dx) f(x)} \geq 
\int_{A}{\mu(dx) \, f(x) \, 1_{f \geq \frac{1}{n}}(x)}
\geq \frac{1}{n} \mu\left(A \, \cap \, \{f \geq \frac{1}{n}\} \right)
> 0
$$ for $n \in \mathbb{N}$ big enough, because
$$
\mu(A) = \lim_{n \to \infty} \mu\left(A \, \cap \, \{f \geq \frac{1}{n}\}.\right)
$$

Comment: I see one problem in your first proof, when you type the ≤ inequality. Let me explain: If I got it right, you're using that, when in A_n, then f≥1/n and hence (1/f)≤n. We know f is strictly positive, but not what values it takes. My point is that certain A_n sets may be null sets. For example, if f(x)≤1/n ∀x, the A_n is null, then f≤1/n and hence we can no longer use 1/f to bound from above neither the ∑ or the∫.
Also on the contradiction proof, taking n→∞, doesn't the right hand side end up =0? How did you get >0 ?

Comment: @oliver He isn't taking a limit. He is using $\mu(A) > 0$ to conclude that $\mu(A \cap \{f \geq \frac{1}{n}\}) > 0$ for some $n$.

Comment: @Mason But there might be no such ${n}$. The only way to get μ(A∩{f≥$\frac{1}{n}$})>0 would be to make the set $B_n$ equal to A, which only occurs when taking limits. For example if f(x)=$\frac{1}{x}$, x>0, it's not bounded from below for any $\frac{1}{n}$, $n \in \mathbb{N}$

Comment: I don't get why you think that the $A_n$ being a null set would be a problem in the first proof to be honest.
For the second proof, if every $\mu\left(A \, \cap \, \{f \geq \frac{1}{n}\} \right)$ would be zero, then the limit could not be $\mu(A) > 0$.

Comment: @oliver Note that $S_n = \{f \geq 1/n\} \nearrow S = \{f > 0\}$. Hence $\mu(S_n) \nearrow \mu(S)$. Thus if $\mu(S) > 0$, then $\mu(S_n) > \frac{1}{2}\mu(S) > 0$ for sufficiently large $n$.

Comment: @unwissen Turns out the thing that was bugging me is resolved with just a few extra lines, as I'd end up with: $(...)\leq \sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} \int_{A}{ nf(x) {1_{A_n}} d\mu }  = \sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}n \cdot \nu\left(A \, \cap \, A_n \right)  \leq \sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}{n \cdot \nu(A)} = 0     \\   $ Thank you sir! I've accepted your answer :)